# Firebase orderByChild and equalTo() queries don't work

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing an Android app with the following Firebase database table:

```
"posts": {
"id_1": {
  "author": "google:111527135678918251124",
  "color": -2960686,
  "creationTime": 1427104145195,
  "text": "my text",
  "title": "my Title",
  "type": 0,
  "visible": true
},
"id_2": {
  "author": "google:111527135678918251524",
  "color": -2960686,
  "creationTime": 1427104145195,
  "text": "my text",
  "title": "my Title",
  "type": 2,
  "visible": true
 },
"id_3": {
  "author": "google:111527135678918251124",
  "color": -2960686,
  "creationTime": 1427104145195,
  "text": "my text",
  "title": "my Title",
  "type": 1,
  "visible": true
 }
}
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve a the posts sorted by a child (sorted by type as an example) and be able to retrieve all the posts with a specific child value (type = 1).
Reading the Firebase docs it seems I have to write the following code, but I don't get the wanted result.

Order by type

```
rootRef.child("posts").orderByChild("type")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            result = (HashMap<String, Post>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I get: an unordered Map of Posts

Type = value

```
rootRef.child("posts").orderByChild("type").equalTo(1, "type").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            result = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            result = result;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    })
```

I get: `null`.
My `Datasnapshot` object has `key = "posts"` and `value = null`

Comment: You want `equalTo(1)` with one argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the ordering, I think the problem is that I'm retrieving data as a `HashMap` which is itself unordered.

As suggested in the comments the second case needs `.equalTo(1)` instead of `.equalTo("type",1)` because it's preceded by the `.orderBy()` method.

Comment: So besides Hashmap what other option do we hai to implement ordered list.