# Sorting Score of every registered user's data in Firebase, Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show every user's score in sorted.

My database structure in Firebase console is looking like below

[image]

I have created two table one is **Score** and one is **User**,

In Score table, I use user's ID, GameA's Score, Game B's Score and Game C's Score

Now I want to show GameA's Score in sorted wise, each user can see sorted data in listview, so he can know that how much he is behind from others...

In Firebase, I have tried with **Query** but could not be able to get success in sorting,

```
   Query queryRef = mDatabase.orderByChild("scores").limitToFirst(100);
    queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Score score=postSnapshot.getValue(Score.class);
                Log.d("test"," values is " + score.getScoreOfGameA()  + " " + score.getUserId());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

with above query result will comes but value is 0, null

it is like below

```
02-02 06:29:09.559 10791-10818/com.firebasedatabaselearn W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "scores"' at / to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance
02-02 06:29:09.562 10791-10791/com.firebasedatabaselearn W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for oFAgix9TlUNS92R2VJaJbNYtH3z2 found on class com.firebasedatabaselearn.module.Score
02-02 06:29:09.562 10791-10791/com.firebasedatabaselearn W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for FrJpw8SMzZYfbECuvhHvbxnbCmh2 found on class com.firebasedatabaselearn.module.Score
02-02 06:29:09.562 10791-10791/com.firebasedatabaselearn D/test:  values is 0 null
02-02 06:29:09.562 10791-10791/com.firebasedatabaselearn W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for NnmawN5gMFVhwaGmZxXgUCPsDMb2 found on class com.firebasedatabaselearn.module.Score
02-02 06:29:09.562 10791-10791/com.firebasedatabaselearn W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for oFAgix9TlUNS92R2VJaJbNYtH3z2 found on class com.firebasedatabaselearn.module.Score
02-02 06:29:09.562 10791-10791/com.firebasedatabaselearn W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for RLEmo9Vyq8Rktwn6Cuz4d6vadml2 found on class com.firebasedatabaselearn.module.Score
02-02 06:29:09.562 10791-10791/com.firebasedatabaselearn W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for FrJpw8SMzZYfbECuvhHvbxnbCmh2 found on class com.firebasedatabaselearn.module.Score
02-02 06:29:09.562 10791-10791/com.firebasedatabaselearn D/test:  values is 0 null
```

can anyone suggest me how can I achive this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally after visiting this [Firebase orderByChild and equalTo() queries don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229387/firebase-orderbychild-and-equalto-queries-dont-work), I have achieved by  below code

```
queryRef = mDatabase.child("scores").orderByChild("scoreOfGameA").limitToLast(100);
        queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Score score=postSnapshot.getValue(Score.class);
                    Log.d("test"," values is " + score.getScoreOfGameA());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: glad you figured it out. The orderByChild method takes a property/column name parameter.

Comment: Thanks alot @TomerBu so what is the use of orderByValue?

Comment: The use case is when your ref has a direct value: mDatabase.child("scores").child("scoreOfGameA").orderByValue();